Pipewire, Wireplumber and Jack problems
Using Ubuntu 22.04 and 6.8.0-40-generic
I did all the install of pipewire, wireplumber and Jackctl with "reinstall".
Following the guide at https://linux.how2shout.com/enable-pipewire-for-audio-and-bluetooth-in-ubuntu-22-04-or-20-04/
All works EXCEPT the line
"sudo cp /usr/share/doc/pipewire/examples/alsa.conf.d/99-pipewire-default.conf /etc/alsa/conf.d/"
There I get the error "File or catalog does not exists". alsa.conf missing and can not be copied.
The line "sudo cp /usr/share/doc/pipewire/examples/ld.so.conf.d/pipewire-jack-*.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/" seems to be accepted.
Rebooting and testing with "pactl info" gives:

Serverstring: /run/user/1000/pulse/native Library protocol version:
35 Server protocol version: 35
Local: Yes Klient index: 239
Blocksize:   65472
Username:    steff
Hostname:    steff-B550-GAMING-X-V2
Server name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 1.2.3)

Server version: 15.0.0
Pre selected samplings freq: float32le 2kan. 48000 Hz
Selected channel mapping: front-left,front-right
Selected recipient:alsa_output.usb-PreSonus_PreSonus_AudioBox_iTwo_AB5C20072767-00.analog-stereo
Pre selected source:alsa_input.usb-PreSonus_AudioBox_iTwo_AB5C20072767-00.iec958-stereo
Cookie: 0e5b:f050

Starting qjackctl gives a truckload of errors:
17:18:49.323 Statistics reset.
17:18:49.325 ALSA connection change.
17:18:49.331 D-BUS: Service is available (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
17:18:49.337 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('engine:sync', 'false'): Invalid container address 'engine':'sync':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
17:18:49.349 ALSA connection graph change.
Tue Aug 27 17:18:49 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'engine':'sync':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.
17:18:54.030 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('engine:verbose', 'false'): Invalid container address 'engine':'verbose':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
Tue Aug 27 17:18:54 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'engine':'verbose':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.
17:18:54.614 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('engine:realtime', 'false'): Invalid container address 'engine':'realtime':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
Tue Aug 27 17:18:54 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'engine':'realtime':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.
17:18:56.110 D-BUS: ResetParameterValue('engine:realtime-priority'): Invalid container address 'engine':'realtime-priority':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
Tue Aug 27 17:18:56 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'engine':'realtime-priority':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.
17:18:56.830 D-BUS: ResetParameterValue('engine:port-max'): Invalid container address 'engine':'port-max':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
Tue Aug 27 17:18:56 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'engine':'port-max':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.
17:18:57.406 D-BUS: ResetParameterValue('engine:client-timeout'): Invalid container address 'engine':'client-timeout':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
17:18:57.934 D-BUS: ResetParameterValue('engine:clock-source'):
Invalid container address 'engine':'clock-source':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
Tue Aug 27 17:18:57 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'engine':'client-timeout':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.
Tue Aug 27 17:18:57 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'engine':'clock-source':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.
17:18:58.502 D-BUS: ResetParameterValue('engine:self-connect-mode'): Invalid container address 'engine':'self-connect-mode':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
17:18:59.014 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('driver:device', 'hw:iTwo'): Invalid container address 'driver':'device':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
Tue Aug 27 17:18:58 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'engine':'self-connect-mode':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.
Tue Aug 27 17:18:59 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'device':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.
17:18:59.534 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('driver:rate', '48000'): Invalid container address 'driver':'rate':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
17:19:00.094 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('driver:period', '1024'): Invalid container address 'driver':'period':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
Tue Aug 27 17:18:59 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'rate':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.
Tue Aug 27 17:19:00 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'period':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.
17:19:01.438 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('driver:nperiods', '2'): Invalid container address 'driver':'nperiods':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
Tue Aug 27 17:19:01 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'nperiods':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.
17:19:02.462 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('driver:softmode', 'false'): Invalid container address 'driver':'softmode':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
17:19:03.326 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('driver:monitor', 'false'): Invalid container address 'driver':'monitor':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
Tue Aug 27 17:19:02 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'softmode':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.
Tue Aug 27 17:19:03 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'monitor':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.
17:19:03.870 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('driver:shorts', 'false'): Invalid container address 'driver':'shorts':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
Tue Aug 27 17:19:03 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'shorts':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.
17:19:04.352 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('driver:hwmeter', 'false'): Invalid container address 'driver':'hwmeter':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
17:19:04.950 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('driver:midi-driver', 'seq'): Invalid container address 'driver':'midi-driver':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
Tue Aug 27 17:19:04 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'hwmeter':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.
Tue Aug 27 17:19:04 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'midi-driver':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.
17:19:05.494 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('driver:duplex', 'true'): Invalid container address 'driver':'duplex':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
17:19:06.086 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('driver:capture', 'hw:iTwo'): Invalid container address 'driver':'capture':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
Tue Aug 27 17:19:05 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'duplex':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.
Tue Aug 27 17:19:06 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'capture':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.
17:19:06.638 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('driver:playback', 'hw:MPK261'): Invalid container address 'driver':'playback':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
17:19:07.222 D-BUS: ResetParameterValue('driver:inchannels'): Invalid container address 'driver':'inchannels':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
Tue Aug 27 17:19:06 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'playback':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.
Tue Aug 27 17:19:07 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'inchannels':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.
17:19:07.758 D-BUS: ResetParameterValue('driver:outchannels'): Invalid container address 'driver':'outchannels':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
17:19:08.245 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('driver:dither', 'n'): Invalid container address 'driver':'dither':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
Tue Aug 27 17:19:07 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'outchannels':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.
Tue Aug 27 17:19:08 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'dither':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.
17:19:08.501 D-BUS: ResetParameterValue('driver:input-latency'): Invalid container address 'driver':'input-latency':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
17:19:09.061 D-BUS: ResetParameterValue('driver:output-latency'): Invalid container address 'driver':'output-latency':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
Tue Aug 27 17:19:08 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'input-latency':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.
Tue Aug 27 17:19:09 2024: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'output-latency':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.
17:19:09.339 D-BUS: JACK server could not be started. Sorry
Tue Aug 27 17:19:09 2024: ERROR: failed to create dbusapi jack client 1.
17:19:14.542 Could not connect to JACK server as client. - Overall
operation failed. - Unable to initialize client. Please check the
messages window for more info.

Status window in jackctl
server name                         (default)
server status                       Stopped
DSP Load                            --
Sampler Rate                        --
Buffer Size                         --
Realtime Mode                       --
Transport State                     --
XRUN count since last server startup 0 (0)
Maximum scheduling delay            --
Time of last reset                  17:42:00
I use reaper and Reaper can not find any MIDI ports
when setting Reaper's device to Jack
Using Pulse audio in Reaper seems to be working
There I get my selected 6 MIDI units
Looks like some files are missing or moved directory since the guide was written.
Any help of this problem would be greatly appreciated
sudo apt -y install wireplumber installs wireplumber without errors.

This needs to be formatted as it is unreadable and the bold part is not in English. This is an English only site. Please edit and correct the question.
